# What would this integral come out as? $\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x}\ dx $

Tags: calculus

What would this integral come out as? $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x}\ dx $$ 
Since the areas on both sides of the y-axis are equal, with one being negative, does that mean that the answer is $0$?
[Graph of $\frac{1}{x}$with shading.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sMhe.jpg)

Comment: No, this improper integral does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

The integral does not converge in the usual sense due to the singularity at the origin. However, your intuition is quite good and using the [cauchy principle value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) and we can write

$$\lim{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-1}^{0-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}+\int_{0+\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}$$

which in this case would indeed [converge to $0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-1+to+1+of+1%2Fx)