# Evaluate $ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Question: Evaluate $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}dx$.

I know this is a Type II improper integral. When I split I get $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}dx=\int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{x}dx+\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{x}dx$.

Then, $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{b \rightarrow 0^-}\int_{-1}^b \frac{1}{x}dx+\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+}\int_a^{1} \frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{b \rightarrow 0^-}\ln|x|{\bigg|_{-1}^b}+\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+}\ln|x|{\bigg|_a^1}$. Now when I evaluate this I get $-\infty+\ln(2)+\infty$. I know $\infty-\infty$ is not $0$. When I check a solution manual it says the answer is divergent, since $\displaystyle \lim_{b \rightarrow 0^-}\int_{-1}^b \frac{1}{x}dx$ is $-\infty$, and we do not have to even evaluate the other integral. But the other integral gives $\infty$.

I am confused. Because in limits, if both limits are divergent, then it does not necessarily mean the addition of them is also divergent. For example if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(x-x)$ is not divergent, even though $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x=\infty$.

What is the difference in a regular limit calculation and an improper integral calculation? Could someone explain this, please?

Edit: The suggested post doesn’t help. I have already understood what that question is asking about. I know infinity-infinity is not zero. My question is about the difference between taking limit of a sum vs having a sum of limits already. Please don’t close this post. Could you please remove your votes for closing?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty} x - \lim_{x\to\infty} x$ is most certainly divergent.  It's possible you meant $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x) = 0$.  Note the difference.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, sorry. I will edit.

Comment: What Brian said is correct. Note that the limit rules that allow you to say $\lim f(x)+g(x)=\lim f(x)+\lim g(x)$ requires $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ to have finite values. In your case, they do not.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But, then, how come we decide the divergence of the improper integral just by evaluating one of them in the sum?

Comment: You're starting with the sum of two limits, not the single limit of a sum.  The sum/difference of two limits converges only if both of the limits converge.  [If you want to go down a rabbit hole, you can look at the Cauchy principal value of this integral instead, in which we have a single limit, _and it exists_, but this would be a different question entirely]

Comment: I see. I think I understood, Thanks!

Comment: Also see [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361673/what-would-this-integral-come-out-as-int-11-frac1x-dx?noredirect=1)

Comment: @Anonymous No, it doesn’t. I have already understood what that question is asking about. I know infinity-infinity is not zero.  My question is about the difference between taking limit of a sum vs having a sum of limits already.

Comment: For those who voted to close, could you please remove your votes? I have already explained in my post why the suggested post doesn’t help.

Comment: @Extremal see the comments on that question. It answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just evalueate this integral, because it depends in how you split the integral.

1. First split (symmetric):
   $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \left( \int_{-1}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx \right)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \left( \log(|-\varepsilon|)-\log(\varepsilon) \right)=0.$$
2. Second split (non symmetric):
   $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \left( \int_{-1}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\int_{c\varepsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx \right)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \left( \log(|-\varepsilon|)-\log(c\varepsilon) \right)=-\log(c).$$
   What you can do is compute the "principal value of the integral".

**Definition.** Let $f$ continuous for $a \leq x<x_{0}$ and $x_{0}<x \leq b$ and absolutely convergent (in the sense that $\int_{a}^{b}|f|<\infty$). The *principal value* of $\int_{a}^{b}f$ is defined by
$$\text{PV}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \left( \int_{a}^{x_{0}-\varepsilon}f(x)dx+\int_{x_{0}+\varepsilon}^{b}f(x)dx \right).$$
Principal values always appear in harmonic analysis while you study singular integrals.